# How to apply custom Fliter formatter in a Slick grid custom cell formatter

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, slickgrid

How to apply custom angular filter formatter in slick-grid custom cell formatter

Suppose I have an angular customer filter formatter that convert the date from one format to another format.

```
var dateFilter = this.$filter('myDateFilterFormatter')('2006-04-07');
```

It returns as 4/7/06.

How can I use myDateFilterFormatter in slick-grid custom cell formatter

I have tried this way

```
this.dateFommatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
            return "<p>"+ value | myDateFilterFormatter +"</p>";
        };
```

and also try

```
this.dateFommatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
                return "<p>"+ this.$filter('myDateFilterFormatter')(value) +"</p>";
            };
```

Both the way ends with error. I am unable to apply custom filter in slick-grid row formatter. Can you please suggest, How can I use custom filter in slick-grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the `dateFormatter` function refers to the function itself.

It's usual to use something like

```
var self = this;

... code ...

this.dateFommatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
    return "<p>"+ self.$filter('myDateFilterFormatter')(value) +"</p>";
};
```

To answer your second query, the code that calls the formatter is, for example

```
function updateCell(row, cell) {
  var cellNode = getCellNode(row, cell);
  if (!cellNode) {
    return;
  }

  var m = columns[cell], d = getDataItem(row);
  if (currentEditor && activeRow === row && activeCell === cell) {
    currentEditor.loadValue(d);
  } else {
    cellNode.innerHTML = d ? getFormatter(row, m)(row, cell, getDataItemValueForColumn(d, m), m, d) : "";
    invalidatePostProcessingResults(row);
  }
}
```

I think you are asking about getting access to `cellNode`.
You can add

```
var cellNode = grid.getCellNode(row, cell);
```

to your formatter if you like.

In the long run, if you find it useful to have access to the cell node, you could modify the `formatter` function, and all calls to it, to add the `cellNode` to the end of the parameter list. This would be a modification to the slickgrid code, however.

EDIT: actually I just tested this and it doesn't work because on cell creation the formatter is called before the cell is created. I have modified the formatter in the latest release of SlickGrid so that instead of returning a string you can optionally return an object `{ text: 'displayText', removeClasses: 'class1 class2', addClasses: 'class1' }` and the classes will be removed and added to the cell when the formatter is applied. Removing a range of classes allows previous formatting classes to be cleared before applying the correct new class.

Comment: Thanks It is working for me. Why there is difference between this and self. Anyhow self is reference of this?

Comment: ```this``` is a special javascript built-in variable that refers to the context of the code. at the top, ```this``` refers to the controller, so we can set the variable ```self``` to it (we could alternatively call it ```controller``` or anything else). within the function, ```this``` refers to the function, not the controller, so we use the variable ```self```, defined earlier, to refer the controller.

Comment: thanks. I understood now. But I have one more issue. How can we call a function using ng-click in the element return by formatter.