# How to call angular service from SlickGrid custom editor

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

How to call angular service from slickgrid custom cell editor.
Below link is mentioned that describes the slickgrid custom cell editor.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Writing-custom-cell-editors

```
function IEditor(args) {
    this.applyValue = function(item,state) {

    // Unable to get the service in the editor context.
    // this.testService is undefined.
    this.testService.getDetails(itemId).get(result =>{
       console.log(result );
    });
  };        
}
```

I am facing an issue to get the service in the editor context. I tried with this and self but no success.

Comment: just use the same technique as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761100/how-to-apply-custom-fliter-formatter-in-a-slick-grid-custom-cell-formatter ... set a variable somewhere in your page code where ```this``` *is* the one you want, and use that variable

Answer (score 0):

the second .this doesn't have the same context of the wrapper function. You should write it like this:

```
 function IEditor(args) {

  var that = this;
  this.applyValue = function(item,state) {

  // Unable to get the service in the editor context.
  // this.testService is undefined.
  that.testService.getDetails(itemId).get(result =>{
     console.log(result );
  });
 };        
}
```

or if you are using ES6:

```
 function IEditor(args) {

  this.applyValue = (item,state) => {

  // Unable to get the service in the editor context.
  // this.testService is undefined.
  this.testService.getDetails(itemId).get(result =>{
     console.log(result );
  });
 };        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not working in my case because time this and that have only Editor context.